# How can I count the number of anagrams of MISSISSIPPI where "I" cannot start or end the word?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

In lecture I was given the following reasoning:

There are 7 options for the first character, 6 options for the last character, and 9! combinations for the 9 characters in between. Then you divide out the repeats -- 4 I's, 4 S's, and 2 P's. So the answer is 7 * 6 * 9! / (4! * 4! * 2!) = 13230

My own reasoning went like this:

There are 11! / (4! * 4! * 2!) combinations if you ignore the restriction on the I's. Then you just subtract out the combinations where I starts and ends the word, which is the same thing as finding out how many combinations are of the form I _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ I, with the possible letters being 1 M, 2 I's (since we used two at the beginning and end), 4 S's, and 2 P's => 9! / (4! * 2! * 2!).

11! / (4! * 4! * 2!) - 9! / (4! * 2! * 2!) = 30870

Where does my reasoning go wrong?

Comment: You want to subtract the words starting with I and the words ending in I, and then add back the words starting and ending with I (since they have been subtracted twice).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only subtracted the combinations both beginning and ending with I. There are cases that the letter either start with I or end with I.

So you want to calculate the number of combinations that start with I: $\frac{10!}{4!*3!*2!}$

and the number of combinations that end with I: $\frac{10!}{4!*3!*2!}$ (should be the same as number of combinations that start with I)

and the number of combinations that both start and end with I : $\frac{9!}{4!*2!*2!}$

So, by principle of inclusion and exclusion, the number of combinations that either start or end with I would be: $\frac{10!}{4!*3!*2!}+\frac{10!}{4!*3!*2!}-\frac{9!}{4!*2!*2!}=21420$

$\frac{11!}{4!*4!*2!}-21420=13230$

Hope that helps!

Comment: Oops, what a dumb mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You were wanting to count words that *neither* begin *nor* end with I.   However you have found the count of words that do not *both* begin *and* end in I.

Let $\Omega$ be the set of all words formed with those letters (distinct permutations of the string), $B$ be the set of those that begin with I, and $E$ those that end with I.   You are after $\lvert B^\complement\cup E^\complement\rvert$

$$\lvert B^\complement\cup E^\complement\rvert~=~\lvert\Omega\rvert-\lvert B\rvert-\lvert E\rvert + \lvert B\cap E\rvert$$

You found instead: $\lvert (B\cap E)^\complement\rvert = \lvert \Omega\rvert -\lvert B\cap E\rvert$